# Add -pl option to maven invoker request

Tags: java, maven, maven-invoker-plugin

I have a little Java program which uses [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/) to run some maven commands programmatically. The Maven routine is basically:

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("clean", "install"));

// module.pomFullPath(workspaceRoot) gets the module location
request.setPomFile(new File(module.pomFullPath(workspaceRoot))); 

InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
```

This runs `mvn clean install` over the module. Now I need to run a command adding options, promtly `mvn -pl !skipThis clean install`

How can I add the `-pl` option to my `request` object in my program? Thanks in advance for your answers/comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your friend:

```
InvocationRequest setProjects(List<String> projects)
```

Comment: Thanks! The documentation for Maven Invoker leaves a lot to be desired, I must say. And the API is not quite intuitive. But it does the job, anyway!